# Getting service credentials at the client side

Tags: wcf

I am trying to get service credentials at the client side by using 
ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name.
But, ServiceSecurityContext.Current is coming out as null.

The service and clients are using windows authentication, Message security mode  and wsHttpBinding. Your help is highly appriciated..thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to get client credential at server or server credential at client ??

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to get server's credential at client then you are probably doing some thing wrong.
If you are doing it other wise, you have use the following setting

```
BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);              
basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType =HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;                
reportService = new ReportingService2005SoapClient(basicHttpBinding, new EndpointAddress(reportServerUrl));
reportService.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowNtlm = false;
reportService.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel =          TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
reportService.ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential =
                    CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

**EDIT**

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicesecuritycontext.aspx)

> Use this class to obtain information about a remote security context
>   at runtime. A security context is created when a client is
>   successfully authenticated and authorized to access a method. When a
>   message is successfully authenticated and authorized, the security
>   information from the client and for the current service instance can
>   be obtained from an instance of this class

Comment: Thank you Anand for the prompt reply.

Comment: Now I am getting confused.. I might have understood the concept totally wrong. Though not sure..
Let me explain what I my understanding is.. 
In WCF, when we talk about authentication, it is always mutual authentication. Client authenticates itself to service and service authenticates itself to client. When the mutual authentication is successful, ServiceSecurityContext object will be populated both on client side and service side. On Client side it will be having server credentials and on service side it will be having client credentials.

Comment: So going buy this, I should be able to access service credentials on the client side.
Please let me know if I am worng…

Comment: ServiceSecurityContext is populated at server side after client sends request. I am looking for some good resource to remove your confusion

Comment: I am using the same. But ServiceSecurityContext.Current is coming as null on client side.. On Server side it works fine..

Comment: Hi Anand,
What I am trying to understand is following text mentioned in msdn article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicesecuritycontext.aspx
“Represents the security context of a remote party. On the client, represents the service identity and, on the service, represents the client identity.”

Comment: If you read this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347790.aspx, it clearly says that "the service security context enables you to determine details about the client credentials and claims used to authenticate with the service.". I am not sure what the it means by the definition in the above link. One valid case scenario for above scenario could be , when wcf is set for bi directional messaging. In this case, even server can initiate the process of communication